# Mysql LIKE operator to find words in stored JSON casesensitive issue

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

I have a column datatype of json in mysql.

Below is the example data in that column

`{"en": "dddd", "ja": null, "zh": null}`

I execute is this query and it run perfectly

`SELECT name FROM product_categories WHERE name like '%d%'`

But when i change the condition from `'%d%'` to `'%D%'`. It doesn't return the result. How can i search the case insensitive words in `json` data type column in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
SELECT name FROM product_categories WHERE UPPER(name) like '%D%'
```

With that you will convert your name to a fully uppercase name and compare that to the uppercase operand.
This should find all lowercase and uppercase d's.

Comment: yes. I got the answer. Actually i am using `Laravel`, i need to query in my controller. i fix that issue by using `DB::raw`. `ProductCategory::where(DB::raw('LOWER(name)'), 'LIKE', '%'. strtolower($r->category) .'%')->get()->pluck("id","name")->toArray();`